# GCP Dataproc create cluster with gpus error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

GCP Dataproc service now supports creating a cluster with GPUs as a beta feature. The problem I met was that when I tried to specify the GPU type, gcloud command line cannot recognize the type I specified.

The gcloud command I use is shown below.

```
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create gpu-cluster \
--zone us-east1-b \
--master-machine-type n1-standard-4 \
--master-boot-disk-size 100 \
--num-workers 2 \
--worker-machine-type n1-standard-1 \
--worker-boot-disk-size 50 \
--initialization-actions gs://15418-initial-script/initialize_cluster.sh \
--worker-accelerator type=nvidia-tesla-p100,count=1
```

I returned with:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.dataproc.clusters.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Insufficient 'NVIDIA_K80_GPUS' quota. Requested 2.0, available 0.0.
```

Anyone knows what happened? Am I using wrong command or is there something wrong with gcloud command line?

Comment: This is happening for me too so I'm reporting it internally (GCP Support). However, I noticed that it picks the correct argument when using a different region

Comment: Filed a public issue too: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79397747. 'Star' it to keep updated, thanks for your collaboration

Comment: Google limit how many resources you can use per-region. Check your quota page and ask for an increase if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to request quota for the GPUs

Check the quotas page for your project to ensure that you have sufficient GPU quota (NVIDIA_K80_GPUS or NVIDIA_P100_GPUS) available in your project. If GPUs are not listed on the quotas page or you require additional GPU quota, request a quota increase.